# Monitor Multiple Pylons Application

Tags: python, monitoring, nginx, pylons

Are there any tools that I can run on my server to monitor multiple Pylons applications?

I need to monitor the number of requests each application receives, how much memory each application is using, how much of the cpu is being used and other stats similar to those. I need to see the stats for each individual Pylons application.

All information needs to be stored in a database for me to retrieve later (preferably SQLite, PostgreSQL, or MySQL).

Thanks

---

*UPDATE*

It is a Unix server and it is running Ubuntu. It's using Nginx.

Each application must store its data in its own database for just the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use something like Zenoss.

There is some specific nginx integration graphs here: http://community.zenoss.org/docs/DOC-7441

Answer (score 1):

If your server is unix-like, you have a lot of tools that helps with processes monitoring such as ps, top, lsof etc.

To monitor the requests to the server, depending on the server you are using, look for webserver logs analyzers (ex. apachetop). I also recommend the performance testing (ApacheBench).

Here's some links:

Top:

http://www.linuxforums.org/articles/using-top-more-efficiently_89.html

Netstat:

http://www.simplehelp.net/2009/01/19/monitor-your-linux-machine-with-netstat/

Apachetop:

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/monitor-your-website-in-real-time-with-apachetop/

ApacheBench:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-performance-benchmarks-a-web-server.html